# Variable declaration that I don't understand in Lua

Tags: lua

I was reading some Lua and doing a little course to use it with Löve 2D, in an example they give declare a variable this way, which I honestly do not understand:

`ballDX = math.random(2) == 1 and 100 or -100`

I've tried to google and read a bit but haven't found a place to specifically explain that. Looking at what it says I identify the obvious, BallDX is equal to a random number between 1 and 2, but from there I get quite confused, what does it mean that the random number is equal to 1 and 100 or -100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a kinda interesting Lua concept

The operator `and` returns its first argument if it is false; otherwise, it returns its second argument.

The operator `or` returns its first argument if it is not false; otherwise, it returns its second argument

In this case `math.random(2) == 1 and 100 or -100` behaves exactly like a ternary operator, it can translate to:

`If math.random(2) equals to 1, set ballDX = 100, otherwise set ballDX = -100`

For example, assume you had a variable called `c`, and you want to assign it a value only if `a` variable is above 10, with a ternary operator you would do this: `c = a > 10 ? a : b`

In Lua you would use `c = a > 10 and a or b`

Comment: oh, it's a ternary operator, I don't thought in that, thank you

Comment: @jsdledezma you can mark the answer as accepted :-)